# Why cant we give array of values to a String in main function in Java?

Tags: java, command-prompt

```
class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String args[4]){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Is it Wrong to give String args[4] ? Why cant we mention any value inside the String args[4] ?But we should get an Output as **Hell**,But there is something wrong.The Code is not executing properly.

Comment: You use invalid syntax.

Comment: ...what?  Where does `"Hell"` come into this?  Why would array length be a part of specifying the method parameters?

Comment: I know it's an invalid syntax,you cant we use String[4] args. Can anyone explain properly.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the `args` as a parameter. The array is created when the program runs. The content of the `args` array is not known at compile time (not even its size), therefore it would not make sense to make assertions at compile time about the size. For this reason an array never contains its length in the type signature.

If you really need to check the size, the correct way is writing a condition, such as:

```
if (args.length != 4) {
    //do some error handling stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like below, and args[] are used when you run your program through command line. In your case you would compile your program and run it using this command `java HelloWorld someArgument1 someArgument2`, here in this command add as many arguments as you want from your command line and access them inside your code. For instance, `args[0]` would be '`someArgument1`' in this case. However if you don't want to give parameters, simply run your program without providing parameters as `java HelloWorld`.

```
class HelloWorld{
public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. Cheers,,

Comment: What you have written the code it works good for me,that's not my question.Why cant we use with String[4] args in main question.

Comment: @VikasGautham It is the main method, you can't define the maximum number of indexes of args. Why would you want to change args length anyways, it would never effect your current print statement.

Comment: Tell me why i should not use String[4] args,What's wrong to use it and why cant we.